# vb.net avoid listview duplicate

Tags: vb.net, listview, duplicates

here is the code to clone my lvList to my LvPrint my problem is how to avoid duplication
or prevent duplicate help

```
    Dim lvi, lvi2 As New ListViewItem
                    If lvList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                        For i As Integer = 0 To lvList.SelectedItems.Count - 1
                            lvi = lvList.SelectedItems(i)
                            lvi2 = CType(lvi.Clone, ListViewItem)
                            lvPrint.Items.Add(lvi2)
                        Next
                    End If
```

Comment: do you want to prevent duplicates from printing or prevent duplicates in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Verify this below, added extra if condition to check selected string already available in lvprint

```
Dim lvi, lvi2 As New ListViewItem
    Dim list As String = ""
    Dim printlist As String = ""
    For j As Integer = 0 To lvPrint.Items.Count - 1
        printlist = printlist & " " & lvPrint.Items(j).Text
    Next
    If lvList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To lvList.SelectedItems.Count - 1
            lvi = lvList.SelectedItems(i)

            If Not list.Contains(lvi.Text) And Not printlist.Contains(lvi.Text) Then
                lvi2 = CType(lvi.Clone, ListViewItem)
                lvPrint.Items.Add(lvi2)
            End If
            list = list & " " & lvi.Text

        Next
    End If
```

Comment: I have test this code locally, when select duplicated text its avoid the second one loaded the first one, are you checking the selected text already in lvPrint list view?

Comment: it will clone the selecteditem from lvList to lvPrint

Comment: I have loaded sample text "Test","Sample","Work","Test", if i select expect "work", press button load the selected item lvPrint loaded with "Test","Sample", the above condition duplicate "Test" string. Let me know is that you want achieve?

Comment: what i want is how to avoid the duplication if lvPrint has already the item selected from lvList

Comment: hi edited the previous code, please get the latest one verify at your end

Comment: @Margz Jacela an important rule of SO is to mark an answer as accepted if that answer solved your problem.